# confusion over async call in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a controller which looks like the below:

```
public IActionResult StaticsMonthly(string id, string from, string to)
{       
    var result = _statdaily.statsMonthly(id, startDate.ToString(), now.ToString());
    return Ok(result) ;
}
```

statsMonthly is an interface signature which I implemented:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<statisticsDaily>> statsMonthly(string id, string dtFrom, string dtTo)
{
    var rslt = await  ( from d in db.statMonth
                    join s in db.masterData on d.m_turbine_id equals s.m_turbine_id
                    where d.m_turbine_id == IPAddress.Parse(id) && d.m_date >= frm
                    group d by d.m_date.Month into g
                    select new statisticsDaily
                    {
                        Date = g.Key.ToString("MMM"),
                        Production = g.Sum(s => s.m_energy_prod),
                        m_wind_speed = g.Average(s => s.m_wind_speed),
                        Availability = g.Average(s => s.m_availability)
                   }
             ).ToListAsync(); 

    return rslt;
}
```

My action returns an `IActionResult`, but inside my action there is a method that async is implemented, in order to achieve the desirable benefit of async, should the action also be async?

Comment: Yes. Currently you’re returning a `Task` and it might never be run. You’re not returning the result of the method call. As far as I know `Ok()` does not run the Task for you

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen so the task should be implemented inside the controller right?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using async/await somewhere in your code, you should go back and add async/await to the entire code flow.
In your case, the `statsMonthly` method is async. Thus, wherever you call this method, it's best to use async as well.

I would therefore rewrite your controller method like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> StaticsMonthly(string id, string from, string to)
{       
    var result = _statdaily.statsMonthly(id, startDate.ToString(), now.ToString());
    return Ok(await result) ;
}
```